# Laptop -> Disable internal screen on lid close / docking station

Tags: laptop, lid

I am an absolute noob on Linux/Ubuntu, so please excuse if this is a silly question...

I am using a Lenovo ThinkPad T450 in a docking station with two external screens connected to displayport. The laptop's lid is always closed.
When booting the laptop to Ubuntu, the internal screen is enabled and set as primary screen although the lid is closed. The external screens are only extensions.

Why is that? How can I change that?

Windows is having a whole other behaviour here and working as expected: when closing the lid the internal screen is completely disabled an only the external screens are enabled. One of the external screens is then set to primary.

On Google I did not find a solution for that, only for "Laptop is going to suspend when lid is being closed", but that is NOT my problem here.

Thanks for your help.

Regards
Lorenz

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem on some of our Lenovo ThinkPad T480.
As it turned out the problem was related to an outdated BIOS Version. Updating to the current Version fixed it.
It even is mentioned in the Changelog (https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles/n24uj23w.txt):

> (Fix) Fix an issue where ThinkPad LCD might be detected when LID
> closed even user set power policy as "Lid Close Do nothing".